# Is there a way to carry on a variable when I use the Promise.all ... then syntax in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

```
Promise.all(user_arr.map((item) =>
                    `endpoint/${item}`).map(fetchJson))
                    .then((responseText) => {
                        obj[item] = responseText[0].result
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
```

In my `Promise.all` API call, I want to carry on the `item` variable so that `obj[item]` knows which item it's referring to. However, this gives me `'item' is not defined` error.

Is there a proper way to getting this done in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: define item in global / parent scope?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to restructure your code so that you close over `item`.

```
Promise.all(
    user_arr.map((item) =>
        fetchJson(`endpoint/${item}`)
            .then((responseText) => {
                obj[item] = responseText[0].result
            })
    )
).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I'd still have the `.catch` in such a way that it handles Promise.all rejections - because you've now changed the code so there is no rejection handler for Promise.all

Comment: For sure, this makes `item` available in the `.then()` callback but why `responseText[0]`? It's not the same `responseText` as in the question where it was delivered by `Promise.all()`. Moreover, performing the complete map is prodigal given that only the first asynchronous response will be used. See my solution.

Comment: I just answered the question, I don't know what `responseText` is nor do I know how `fetchJson` works. I don't think those details are even relevant to be honest.

Comment: You don't need to know `fetchJson` works but you do need to understand (as I'm sure you alread ydo) that `Promise.all()` delivers an array of whatever `fetchJson` dlivers. In the question, `responseText` is Promise.all()'s responses, whereas in your answer `responseText` is a single response from `fetchJson()`. See my answer.

Comment: I think the only assumption we can make is that the user wanted to map each item to an object property. There is no indication what `responseText` is supposed to be or how it is to be consumed. I could argue that `responseText` is an array and the user only wanted the first element. It doesn't really matter though, I think the fact that the answer was accepted is indication enough that the other details are not relevant.

Answer (score -1):

If you know that only the first element of `responseText` will be used, there's no point mapping all of `user_arr`.

Instead, start with `user_arr[0]` and side-step the map.

```
var item = user_arr[0];
fetchJson(`endpoint/${item}`))
.then(responseText => {
    obj[item] = responseText.result;
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Have courage of your convictions, whoever you are.